# Red border and box shadow problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, blogger

I am working on a custom theme for a blog on Blogger, which looks fine in both Chrome and Firefox, but when viewed in IE9, there is an odd red border around every post and the box shadow that I got rid of is still there. If the website is viewed in IE8 or IE7 mode, the border is white. The blog looks fine until something loads, and then it is messed up. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

For Blogger specs, I am using the Picture Window theme as the base for this new one, and I am just using the custom CSS box in the template designer. The custom css that I am using is posted below:

```
.post-outer {
border-radius:none;
border:none;
background:#3c3c39;
color:#eeeeee;
box-shadow:0pt 0pt 5px #272725 inset;
border-radius:10px;
}

.date-posts {
border:none;
}

.main-outer {
background:none;
border:none;
box-shadow:none;
}

.column-right-outer {
padding-top:20px;
}

.column-right-outer .widget a {
color:#666666;
}

div.post-footer {
border-top:1px dashed #555555;
margin-top:15px;
padding-top:10px;
}

#navbar {
display:none;
}

div.footer-outer {
display:none;
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
}

.footer-inner {
padding:0 20px 0 20px;
}

div.feed-links {
display:none;
}

div#Attribution1 {
display:none;
}

body {
min-height:5px;
padding-top:15px;
}

.blog-pager a {
color:#555553;
}
```

The url for the blog is here: http://grandambiance.blogspot.com/

Comment: Not seeing the border in IE9 here. Clear your cache?

Comment: I have tried to clear my cache, and it doesn't help because then the browser mode is switched and the border appears white. I don't want that white border or the box shadow that is vaguely visible around the whole blog area.

Comment: You have `border-radius:none;` Where did that come from?

Comment: I was trying to see if anything at all would change the border.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a template that has this meta tag in it:

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

IE8 or IE9 will emulate IE7 when this meta tag is present, and some of the styles you're using aren't supported by IE7. So this should at least help you understand why there are some anomalous behaviors.

You can try removing the meta tag to see what happens. Maybe it will work the way you're expecting, but it might also become even more munged because the template is employing IE7 specific functionality, hence forcing later browsers to emulate IE7. I tried removing the same meta tag in [my blog](http://formlesspoet.blogspot.com/) when I was trying to get some CSS3 styles to work, but it only made matters much worse. But you could get lucky.

Barring this, you can check to see if there are any IE7 specific properties that will let you use some of the CSS3 you want.

If it's any consolation, though the page looks a little different in IE9 than in other browsers, it still looks pretty nice and as if the styling was intentional.

Comment: I just saved a copy of the web page and removed the meta tag in question. Looks fine in IE9 after doing so. But consider creating some special provisions for IE7 and IE8 as needed. You can reference this page for some information about how to go about it:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: I have, in fact, tried removing that line, but the red border is still there if the browser is in IE9 mode, and it is white if it is in any lower version of IE. I am fine if it is a white border, but the red is just too odd.

Comment: Ah bummer. It looked fine for me after I removed that meta tag. Have you tried looking at it from other computers as well?

Comment: Indeed, I have! Unfortunately it still looks the same, though one plus is that with the meta tag, IE looks at it in IE7 mode, so most people shouldn't see the border as red.